# css grid stretch row contents to fit parent container

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is there a way to get grid items to stretch the length of the parent container? I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

basically im trying to build a calendar with grid because idk it seemed like the best option. ive got the 7 columns and they stretch the width of the parent container. however, the grid rows do not. i've tried loads of potential solutions from SO and other places but none of them seem to work.

setting `days` `height:100%;` causes it to stretch too far down the page and overflow, which is undesirable. if i take that out, then they don't fill in the space and just bunch up. ideally I would like 7 x 5 with square boxes, but at this point i'll take evenly spaced rectangles. what am I doing wrong or misunderstanding?

here's a snippet: (css is scss)

```
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.calendar {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  //remove italics is for testing. delete after done
  font-style: normal;
  position: relative;
}


.month {
  padding: 7rem 10rem;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
}

.month ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;

  & a{
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
}

// use grid 7 x 5 (modify for february in js)
.weekdays {
  background: #222;
  color: #eee
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7,1fr);
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}


.days {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-decoration: none;

  background: #eee;

  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(5,1fr) / repeat(7,1fr); // rows / columns
  justify-content: stretch;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  
  & > li {
    background: #www;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="main-container">
  <div class="calendar">
    <div class="month">
        <ul>
            <li class="prev"><a href="#" class="month__prev">&#10094</a></li>
            <li>August<br><span style="font-size:18px">2020</span></li>
            <li class="next"><a href="#" class="month__prev">&#10095</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="weekdays">
        <li>Monday</li>
        <li>Tuesday</li>
        <li>Wednesday</li>
        <li>Thursday</li>
        <li>Friday</li>
        <li>Saturday</li>
        <li>Sunday</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="days">
        <li><a href="#" class="day">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="day">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="day"> 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="day"> 4</a></li>
        ...
<!--and so on-->
```

logic is: wrap all the grid containers in a `flex` item because `flex` is the "layout" and `grid` is the organisation.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the result you are getting and a screenshot for the desired result.?

Comment: It's not clear though the problem seems easy to fix, Can you put up a working code snippet on jsfiddle or something similar ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution that worked. I added a `display:flex` and set it to column in a parent element but I forgot where because I was just trial and erroring a lot of things. I think it was the `calendar` element since that's not in the OP. it gave me this output which is what I was looking for (sorry for the colours).

[image]